# JsonConverter and EntityData

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, azure, json.net

I'm using Azure with a database-first EF approach. One of my entities in the Azure web service is defined as follows:

```
public class Company : EntityData
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

It inherits the Id property from EntityData. The Id property is of type string.

In the client, I have the following entity:

```
class Company
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(IntConverter))]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see above, I need to convert the Id from string to int.

I've created the following JSON converter:

```
class IntConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
        object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value == null)
            return 0;

        int num;
        if (Int32.TryParse(reader.Value.ToString(), out num))
            return num;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, 
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString());
    }
}
```

It's working fine but because this is my first JSON converter, I'm not sure if I created it correctly. I saw examples of converters and they used existingValue rather than reader.Value. In my case, existingValue is always 0.

Is the above implementation correct?

Comment: The `existingValue` is the existing value, and since `Company.Id` is never assigned directly on the property or from ctor it will always be 0.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about reviewing working code. It belongs on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: It's good that at least before closing my question I got great insights from DBC :) I was not aware that it was off-topic. Thanks again DBC for your help.

Comment: @ata6502 - the question wouldn't get deleted, it would get moved to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  It's a well written question but it might be better for that site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is *basically* correct.

The `existingValue` is the value previously existing in the parent c# model.  By passing it into the converter, Json.NET allows the converter to work when [populating](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PopulateObject.htm) an existing model or a read-only collection.  For instance, if you have a pre-allocated read-only property with a converter:

```
public class RootObject
{
    readonly ObservableCollection<SomeClass> _collection = new ObservableCollection<SomeClass>();

    [JsonConverter(typeof(ObservableCollectionConverter<SomeClass>>)]
    public ObservableCollection<SomeClass> { get { return _collection; } }
}
```

Then the [`ReadJson()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) method of `ObservableCollectionConverter<SomeClass>` will be passed the pre-allocated `_collection` value and be able to add items to it.

That being said, there are a few improvements to be made:

1. In [`WriteJson()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_WriteJson.htm) you call `value.ToString()`.  There is a possibility that `ToString()` can return a culturally specific string, e.g. decimal points might get inserted for the [`NumberGroupSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator(v=vs.110).aspx).  Instead, you should serialize in an [invariant format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.invariantinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) as follows:

   ```
   public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,
       JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
       // Int32 implements the IConvertible interface which has a ToString() overload
       // that takes an IFormatProvider specification.  Pass the invariant format to guarantee
       // identical serialization in all cultures.
       var convertible = (IConvertible)value;
       serializer.Serialize(writer, convertible.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
   }
   ```
2. A similar fix would need to be made in `ReadJson()`:

   ```
       int num;
       if (Int32.TryParse(reader.Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out num))
           return num;
       else
           return 0;
   ```
3. Your `ReadJson()` is not resilient against unexpected data.  For instance, if the JSON passed in actually has an array or object value (e.g. `{"unexpectedProperty": "unexpectedValue"}`) then the `JsonReader` will not be properly advanced to the end of the input.  You should check the [`reader.TokenType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_TokenType.htm) and handle bad data appropriately, e.g.:

   ```
   public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
       object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
       switch (reader.TokenType)
       {
           case JsonToken.Null:
               return null;

           case JsonToken.Integer:
               // Input was already an integer.  Return it
               return (int)JToken.Load(reader);

           case JsonToken.String:
               {
                   int num;
                   if (Int32.TryParse(reader.Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out num))
                       return num;
                   else
                       return 0;
               }

           default:
               throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token {0} at path {1}", reader.TokenType, reader.Path));
       }
   ```

   Or, if you prefer to consume and discard the unexpected data without throwing an exception (I don't recommend this) you could use [`JsonReader.Skip()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_Skip.htm):

   ```
           default:
               Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Unexpected token {0} at path {1}", reader.TokenType, reader.Path));
               reader.Skip();
               return 0;
   ```
4. [`JsonConverter.CanConvert`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanConvert.htm) is not called when the converter is applied via attributes.  However, if you added the converter to [`JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm) then returning `true` from `CanConvert` would be a problem.  Instead, I'd recommend either throwning a `NotImplementedException` or properly implementing the method:

   ```
   public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
   {
       return objectType == typeof(int) || objectType == typeof(int?);
   }
   ```

Thus, your final converter might look like:

```
class IntConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(int) || objectType == typeof(int?);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
        object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.Null:
                return null;

            case JsonToken.Integer:
                // Input was already an integer.  Return it
                return (int)JToken.Load(reader);

            case JsonToken.String:
                {
                    int num;
                    if (Int32.TryParse(reader.Value.ToString(), NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out num))
                        return num;
                    else
                        return 0;
                }

            default:
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unexpected token {0} at path {1}", reader.TokenType, reader.Path));
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Int32 implements the IConvertible interface which has a ToString() overload
        // that takes an IFormatProvider specification.  Pass the invariant format to guarantee
        // identical serialization in all cultures.
        var convertible = (IConvertible)value;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, convertible.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
    }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M4EmK3) showing both the strict and tolerant versions of the final converter.